# How to truncate table with SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to **truncate** table but when column value equals `NULL`

```
truncate table FB_Player where FB_Player.Status ='NULL'
```

Comment: `TRUNCATE TABLE` truncates (deletes) the **entire table** - you cannot limit it to just certain rows..... [see the relevant TechNet documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx) - **freely** available to **everyone** - there is no `WHERE` clause on a `TRUNCATE TABLE` command....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can not Use Where Clause with truncate. Truncate clears all the data from a table without any condition. Instead you use Delete command.

Answer (score 9):

You are looking for `Delete` not `Truncate`.

You cannot use where clause with [TRUNCATE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260621%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

You can try this:-

```
delete from FB_Player where FB_Player.Status is NULL
```

From [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncate_%28SQL%29)

> You cannot specify a WHERE clause in a TRUNCATE TABLE statement—it is
>   all or nothing.

Comment: but the Table IDs not arranged i need also the tables IDs for the rest rows as " 1, 2 , 3 ...etc " not "3 ,12 ,15 ...etc.